# Web Desktop Environment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, desktop-environment, html, web

I have a mad idea, I want to make my own Linux distro (maybe on *buntu system) with a DE which I could develop with HTML5, CSS and JS. To start, I just want to make my DE a web page (I don't talk about a Thin Client).

Comment: The answer to your question is "no", I am not sure how that is going to help you.

Comment: [This sort of thing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/305865/88378) seems to be popular lately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnome dev's have already halfway done this, per the gnome journal blog - [applications which use GTK+ 3.0 library can be styled with CSS](https://thegnomejournal.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/styling-gtk-with-css/).

> Starting with GTK+ 3.0, we’re replacing the old theming layer with a more modern one. Designers will find it more powerful and immediate, and it’s more intuitive for the masses.

The main C function that provides this functionality is [GTKCssProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html)

- [api reference overview of using CSS with GTK](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html)

I use CSS to style the GUI aspects of my Gnome terminal, but still use `gsettings` to configure the programmatic behavior and some the colors related to default font and background etc and it works, but its alot of reading about gnome and its an API under development which means it can be subject to breaking changes.